# Jurisdiction in this case?

Tags: contract-law

I signed an internet contract with a fake address in California. I live in Georgia.

Am I under California or Georgia jurisdiction?

Contract does not specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the contract. If the contract explicitly says if there are any argues of law it will be solved under this jurisdiction it normally does. However if the contract does not outline that normally there will be a fight of which jurisdiction is applied. It will be determined by the facts and different circumstances of the case. Just remember you can not have two jurisdictions at the same time

Comment: It's entirely possible, and not incredibly uncommon, for multiple jurisdictions to apply at the same time. That's why the fight happens in the first place, and often is only about who gets the first shot, not who gets the only shot.

Comment: Your final sentence is completely wrong - you can and usually do operate under several jurisdictions at once. For example, in the question above there are issues of Federal law, California and/or Georgia law, possibly local law and the law of wherever the service is - thats without considering any choice of law provisions in the contract.